# java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.v.finalize() timed out after 10 seconds

Tags: java, android

When check error in crashlytics im get a error `Fatal Exception: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.v.finalize() timed out after 10 seconds`.
How to fix it?